Wireguard server restart required after server public IP address changes
I have a wireguard server(version: 1.0.20210914-1) running on Debian 12 and a few clients, mostly OpenWrt routers connecting to it, I have a problem that is happening every time the server changes its public IP address.When it happens I restart the openWrt router(wireguard  client) and it should automatically reconnect and work again(since it points to a dynamic DNS which had been updated with the new server IP address), but I have noticed that for some reason the client doesn't really reconnect correctly unless I perform a server restart. After restarting the server side process as well with systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0 then the connection is establishing again and everything starts to work again. It looks like from wg show on the server that until I restart the wireguard server process the handshake with the client is not completed correctly...
The question is: why after a server public IP address change, restarting the client is not enough ? Why do I have to restart the server process as well ?
The configuration is pretty basic like:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxx
Address = 172.10.10.1/28
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 172.10.10.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 172.10.10.3/32


Why doesn't your business ISP contract include a static public address?

Is the client able to talk to 172.10.10.1 through the tunnel, or is there no handshake at all?

No handshake at all...

I just want to understand your setup a bit better, is this a server on a normal internet connection or a machine in the cloud? Is the server behind a router with port forwarding or does the server itself own the public IP?

normal fibre internet connection behind a router and with NAT

That's really strange. Have you run tcpdump or wireshark or something to look at the incoming traffic on the server?

Before a WireGuard connection can be used, the two sides of the connection perform a handshake to negotiate an ephemeral encryption key to use for the next 2-3 minutes. After performing a handshake, each side won't allow the other to initiate a new handshake for at least 2 minutes; and they won't accept packets encrypted with that key after 3 minutes.
If during this 2-minute window, you restart one side of the connection, it will forget the ephemeral encryption key, and try to perform a new handshake with the other side of the connection. The other side of the connection will not allow this, however, until the 2-minute window has elapsed.
So if you restart one side of a WireGuard connection, you may have to wait up to 2 minutes before you can use it again. Alternatively, you can restart the other side of the connection to force it, too, to forget about the previous handshake.
If you want to reconfigure a WireGuard connection without restarting it and causing it to forget the previous handshake, you can do so via its command-line interface. For example, if the output of wg show looks like this:
# wg show
interface: wg0
  public key: /TOE4TKtAqVsePRVR+5AA43HkAK5DSntkOCO7nYq5xU=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51821

peer: fE/wdxzl0klVp/IR8UcaoGUMjqaWi3jAd7KzHKFS6Ds=
  endpoint: 203.0.113.123:51822
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.0/8
  latest handshake: 46 seconds ago
  transfer: 123.45 MiB received, 234.56 MiB sent

You could run the following command to update the endpoint of the fE/wdxzl0klVp/IR8UcaoGUMjqaWi3jAd7KzHKFS6Ds= peer to use a new IP address:
# wg set wg0 peer fE/wdxzl0klVp/IR8UcaoGUMjqaWi3jAd7KzHKFS6Ds= endpoint 203.0.113.234:51822

And if you keep a DNS record updated to point to the peer's current endpoint IP address, you can automate this process by running a script like the wireguard-tools reresolve-dns.sh every 15 seconds (or whatever interval is appropriate in your case).
